# How to merge 2 seperate lines in 1 line?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

Basically this is the text

```
data
data2
someotherdata
someotherdata2
```

And i want them to merge like this

```
data:data2
someotherdata:someotherdata2
```

Is there any way i can make this work? (on notepad++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Find/Replace dialog, make sure "dot matches newline" is off and regex mode is on, then replace all `^(.+)\r?\n?(.+)\r?\n?` with `$1:$2`.

Comment: instead of data:data2 It also adds data:data2someothedata

Comment: Oh i fixed with adding a space between them, thank you a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\K\R`
- Replace with: `:`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
.+          : 1 or more any character but newline
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
\R          : any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
data:data2
someotherdata:someotherdata2
```